# TransferSpreadSheet gives error 3027 "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only."

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to export the results of a dynamic SQL statement but keep getting the error 3027 "Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.". I'm using Access 2003. GetYearFromDirName(sFolder) is parsing out a year from a directory structure and using that as a calculated column in the SQL results.

Here is the code in question:

```
sSQL = "SELECT INDEXDB1.IFIELD1 AS TestArea, INDEXDB1.IFIELD2 AS TSID, INDEXDB1.IFIELD3 AS MapCoord, " _
    & "INDEXDB1.IFIELD4 AS Community, INDEXDB1.IFIELD5 AS Address, INDEXDB1.IFIELD6 AS DocNum, " _
    & "'" & GetYearFromDirName(sFolder) & "' AS Yr FROM INDEXDB1;"

'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , sSQL, sFolder & "\" & BoxNum & ".csv"
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "ExportRecs", acFormatXLS, sFolder & "\" & BoxNum & ".csv"

SaveToExcel sSQL, sFolder & "\" & BoxNum & ".csv"
```

Calls:

```
Public Sub SaveToExcel(strSQL As String, strFullFileName As String)
Dim strQry As String
Dim db As Database
Dim Qdf As QueryDef

On Error GoTo SaveToExcel_err

strQry = "TempQueryName"

Set db = CurrentDb
'Set Qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(strQry, strSQL)

'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, strQry, strFullFileName, True

'DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strQry

With db
    ' Create permanent QueryDef.
    Set Qdf = .CreateQueryDef(strQry, strSQL)
    ' Open Recordset and print report.
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel3, strQry, strFullFileName, True
    ' Delete new QueryDef because this is a demonstration.
    .QueryDefs.Delete Qdf.Name
    .Close
End With


Exit Sub

SaveToExcel_err:
    MsgBox Error & " " & Err & " in sub SaveToExcel. Close program and start over."

End Sub
```

Is there a better way to export dynamic SQL statement results? In the end, I need a CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

You may open it in Excel, but CSV is a *text* format, so you need to use `DoCmd.TransferText` instead of `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. Manually go through the export once using the Export Data Wizard. As you do so, you'll wand to create and name a Export Specification. This will specify commas as the delimiter and double quotes as text delimiters. The name of the export spec you created is passed as the second argument to `TransferText`.

Comment: That was a good, constructive comment that pointed out a real problem with my code. Unfortunately, the name of the export file is dynamic too, so I couldn't use it.

Comment: I ended up looping through the recordset using the text file writing API.

Comment: I had the same problem, this was related to the file name i tried to give the export file. It already existed and ended with .xlsx instead of .csv. Chaning the name to .csv solved the problem.